# indesign: starts number from 1 mid way through doc

Tags: adobe-indesign, creative-cloud, numbering

I have a 32 single page document created in indesign and i have numbered the pages but at page 27 the numbering reverts back to 1. How do i change this?

Comment: We can only guess with this info. Do you have chapters, mixed layouts? Are you using page numbers on master pages or on individual pages?

Answer (score 2):

If the numbering is done in the correct way and not simply typed in at every page, it would mean that the document is probably divided into **[sections that define numbering](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/numbering-pages-chapters-sections.html)**.

If you want to get rid of those sections, select the pages where the numbering starts again from 1 and right-click the selected pages and choose the *Numbering & Section Options*. There deselect the *Start of section* option, accept and your page numbers for those pages should continue the numbering of the rest of the document.